# Android : MPAndroidChart how to remove left side line

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

for Line chart i'm using mp android chart i want to remove the line which is left side of the graph not the gridlines.

code:-

```
    chart.setGridBackgroundColor(128);
    chart.setBorderColor(255);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setDescription("");
    chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(true);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.invalidate();
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this following code,

```
 YAxis leftAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
```

You can enable or disable gridline by,

```
lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);

XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
```

**UPDATE**

```
    chart.setGridBackgroundColor(128);
    chart.setBorderColor(255);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.setPinchZoom(false);
    chart.setDescription("");
    chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(true);
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(true);//enable this too
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);//enable for grid line
    chart.getYAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);//disable vertical line
    chart.invalidate();
```

Comment: by this GridLines will not be  visible

Comment: check out the answer

Comment: still not working . i had updated  my code  in question.

Comment: what is not working did it removed the yaxis or it removed the grid line and also change this to chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);

Comment: check the updated part and replace it with your code

Comment: By your code i'm getting horizontal and vertical gridlines. my requirement is to get onlly horizontal lines (i had got ) but i'm getting the vertical line extra as shown in above image

Comment: if it helped accept the answer and close this question

Answer (score 9):

I had got by adding following line

```
leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

Comment: this removed the axisline but the value near to the axis is not showing properly when its removed

Answer (score 1):

If the X Axis line is to be removed then use
`chart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);`